# Java Swing JTable - get right rowindex after sort

Tags: java, swing, sorting, checkbox, jtable

I've been stuck with a problem in Java.
[Image showing the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjgdD.png)

The problem is:
I have a JTable with 2 Columns (in the Picture 4 for testing purpose): one is a Checkbox and the second one is a String.
Whenever the User checks a Checkbox the Position Column will count a Number up, so the first checked Checkbox will get the Position '1', the second checked Checkbox will get the Position '2' and so on.

When the User checks out one Checkbox with lets say the Position 5 out of 10 items, the rows with the Position 6 and up are going to get count one down and the cell with the Position 5 will be set as an Empty String ("").

This works but the Problem I got is that when:

1. the User checks multiple Checkboxes,
2. then sorts the Table
3. and then tries to check almost any Checkboxes

which will result in a screwing up the columns as seen in the Picture.

In my Example Picture you can see additionally the 2 more Columns:
the Column Row, which is given at the start, where the Table isn't Sorted
and the Column RowIndexToModel, which shows the Position of the Rows but converted to the row inside the Vector, well i thought that but doesn't seem so.

Here is the **Example Class**:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Example extends JFrame {
    private JTable tbl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Example frame = new Example();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public Example() {
        Object[] colNames = {"Checkbox", "Position"};
        Object[][] rows = {{false, ""}, {false, ""},{false, ""},{false, ""},{false, ""},{false, ""},{false, ""}};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, colNames);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        tbl = new JTable(model)
        {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        tbl.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        tbl.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                row = tbl.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                if (e.getColumn() == 0) {
                    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                    Boolean checked = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(row, 0);//getting if boolean got checked or not
                    if (checked) {
                        int maxCount = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            String curValue = (String)model.getValueAt(i, 1);
                            if(curValue != null && !curValue.equals("") && Integer.valueOf(curValue) > maxCount)
                                maxCount = Integer.valueOf(curValue); //get highest number in tbl
                        }
                        maxCount++;
                        model.setValueAt(String.valueOf(maxCount),row, 1); //set highest number + 1
                    } else {
                        String columnString = (String)model.getValueAt(row, 1); //getting position
                        int tmpPos = Integer.valueOf(columnString);

                        for (int index = 0; index < model.getRowCount(); index++) {
                            int indexSorted = tbl.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
                            String curValue = (String)model.getValueAt(indexSorted, 1);
                            //get if current number is higher than unchecked value
                            if (curValue != null && !curValue.equals("") && Integer.valueOf(curValue) > tmpPos) {
                                int curValueToChange = Integer.valueOf(curValue) - 1;
                                model.setValueAt(String.valueOf(curValueToChange),indexSorted, 1); 
                            }
                        }
                        model.setValueAt("",row, 1); 
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tbl);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, gbc);
    }
}
```

PS:The code is written for this Example, so please dont wonder that it doesn't follow general Coding Standards. Sorry if my Code makes your Eyes bleed. ;)

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: i tried to structure my Question for a better overview of the Problem and made the Code a bit more readerfriendly (i think), sorry if it hard to understand, if there are questions i will be trying to answer them.

EDIT2: added Code of a Simple JFrame so the you can Copy&Paste Code to see the Problem for yourself

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for giving me feedback on the Question. I've tried to make it more clean and easier to read. The length of the Code seems maybe to long but i tried my best to just show the part where the Problem happens.

Comment: Please re-read the important links that @AndrewThompson has given you in his comment as I think that you may be missing the most important points to be found there. For best help, you will want to post a small *compilable and runnable* program. This is code that is small enough to post it in its entirety here as code-formatted text, code that we can copy into our IDE's, that compiles, that runs for us and that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: To add to the advice of @HovercraftFullOfEels. If an MCVE/SSCCE has 200 lines of code, all necessary to make it compile cleanly, and run to demonstrate the problem, it is IMO an MCVE/SSCCE. The only reason that the words minimal/short start those descriptions is that too often people leave huge areas of code in that are not relevant to the problem. Often removing the unnecessary code indirectly leads to the person who would ask the question, spotting the problem themselves. But if code is honed down to minimal/short without making the problem clear - the most important parts are then ..

Comment: .. as mentioned in the **rest** of the respective phrases. Make it code that we can all copy, paste, run and actually see the problem, without any further changes or additions. If there is anything you've read in those two links that is not clear to you, don't be afraid to ask. Either of us, as well as many others, can explain further.

Comment: Added Code so a Simple JFrame with the Table is visible. I hope by seeing it for yourself the Problem will be better understandable.

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for everything, ive figured out that my Problem was that i misunderstood "convertRowIndexToModel" and without it it is working as wanted.

Comment: *"..figured out that my Problem.."* Glad you got it sorted! :) Now you might write up an answer under 'Answer my own question' (or WTE) or simply delete the entire question using the link below the question tags.

Answer (score 2):

I have found out that my Example shows false Values because:

When i convert the row with

```
tbl.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
```

i get the wrong row Index.

After i removed the 2 lines where i converted the row index i got the right Values.